# Can't attach Javascript to theme

Tags: theme-development, javascript

I'm currently learning theme development, and tweaking the twentytwelve theme. I've got an external javascript file I'm trying to link, but it won't seem to register. The codex tells me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/yourscript.js"></script>
```

which I've changed the filename, to suit my purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>//trans.js"></script>
```

However, this is still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: You really are missing something! External resources are added with the [enqueue methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) not by hardcoding in script tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the file tree for your theme, but you do have two slashes `//` in your `<script>` tag. Try this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/trans.js"></script>`